# PyErr_NewException gives name must be module.class in python

Tags: python, ctypes

Trying to create a c type exception in python 3.6 using ctypes.pythonapi, this is my code:

```
exc = ctypes.pythonapi.PyErr_NewException("error_logging.BackgroundTimeoutError")
raise exc
```

I keep getting this error:

```
SystemError: PyErr_NewException: name must be module.class
```

I am in the error_logging module and the BackgroundTimeoutError is a class defined in this module. I can't find any answers. What am I missing?

Comment: In case it's not obvious how that applies: `PyErr_NewException` thinks you're just passing it `"e"`.

Comment: As usual with `ctypes` issues, make sure to set `.argtypes` and `.restype` appropriately and don't let `ctypes` guess how to convert a Python type to a C type.  Then `ctypes` will fail when you pass the wrong number of args or type (as is the case here).  Python `str` is converted to `wchar_t*` by default.  You want `bytes` (b'error...') and there are two more parameters.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do in any case.  You are in Python, why can't you `raise error_logging.BackgroundTimeoutError()`?

Comment: Why not just simply defining your exception?

Comment: using a b-string worked! But now I am getting this error: TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases. this is the code ctypes.pythonapi.PyErr_NewException(b"error_logging.BackgroundTimeoutError", ctypes.pythonapi.PyExc_Exception, 0). and BackgroundTimeoutError derives from Exception

Comment: made a new question with this info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68524801/getting-typeerror-metaclass-conflict-from-pyerr-newexception