# getting TypeError: metaclass conflict from PyErr_NewException

Tags: python, ctypes

Trying to create a c type exception in python 3.6 using ctypes.pythonapi, this is my code:

```
exc = ctypes.pythonapi.PyErr_NewException(b"error_logging.BackgroundTimeoutError", ctypes.pythonapi.PyExc_Exception, 0)
raise exc
```

I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

The BackgroundTimeoutError is a class that derives from Exception:

```
class BackgroundTimeoutError(Exception):
```

I also tried the following:

```
PyErr_NewException(b"error_logging.BackgroundTimeoutError", ctypes.py_object(BaseException), 0)
```

Then I get this error:

```
TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException
```

Comment: Again, *why* are you doing this?  If `BackgroundTimeoutError` is already defined in Python, why aren't you just doing `raise error_logging.BackgroundTimeoutError()`?

Comment: @MarkTolonen its because I am raising an error to another thread using `PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc`